# Table view algorithm

Tags: iphone, xcode

This is my code for the table view cell loading:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CellView" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = nibLoadedCell;
    }

    if (photosArray.count > 0) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {                
            UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:i];
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            button.layer.borderWidth = 2;
            button.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
            button.clipsToBounds = YES;

            //Add images to the button
            UIImage *btnImg;
            if ((indexPath.row * 3) + i < photosArray.count) {
                btnImg = [photosArray objectAtIndex:((indexPath.row) * 3 + i)];
                NSLog(@"%d",(indexPath.row) * 3 + i);
            }

            [button setBackgroundImage:btnImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            button.tag = imageButtonTag;
            imageButtonTag--;                
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"%d",cell.contentView.subviews.count);
    for (UIButton *button in cell.contentView.subviews) {

        if ([button backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal] == nil) {
            [button removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    return cell;    
}
```

I already have a custom cell i created that holds 3 buttons.

I also have an array of different images.

The code above should create a tableview with 3 button/ at each cell and each button has a background image over it.

The issue is, that when scrolling down i see that some of the images repeat them selves. That couldn't come from the source array of photos, i am 99% sure that my array is fine.

Can someone see what am i doing wrong? I've been looking at it for so long and i can't see my mistake..

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible you're going out of bounds with your array? It seems like if you wind up with a cell that has indexPath.row * 3 + 1 > your array count you'll have repeating images since the images themselves don't get cleared out of the buttons.

Comment: Where should i release these images? At the end of the for loop?

Comment: I'm not sure that's the solution… Things should be autoreleased. and not all pictures are repeating.. The first batch of images (21 images) that gets into the first page don't repeat. Also images number 22 23 24 that don't show in the first page don't repeat. Only image 25 and on are repeating...

Comment: It's not about releasing the images exactly. Basically what i think is happening is let's say you have 10 cells but only 25 images, after you get past the 8th cell `if ((indexPath.row * 3) + i < photosArray.count) {
                btnImg = [photosArray objectAtIndex:((indexPath.row) * 3 + i)];
                NSLog(@"%d",(indexPath.row) * 3 + i);
            }
`
won't get called again, which means the cells that are still being created are going to use whatever images are currently stored for each cell:

`UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:i];`

Comment: What you can do is set `[button setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];` right after `UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:i];`. If you have images ready for that cell you'll see no difference, but if you run out of images they'll show up blank instead of repeating images.

Comment: Did that help? Should I post an answer?

Comment: Didn't help… Nothing else?